# Count and display duplicates across multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g I have a table with the following fields:

***Name, Type, Ref***

I want to get a count of the number of duplicates. The definition of it being a duplicate is that for two records the Name and Type are the same but the Ref is different.

I would also like to be able to list the records which have duplicates (only showing one record per duplicate)

**The following would be a duplicate:**

Record 1: Name1, Large, 0001

Record 1: Name1, Large, 0002

**The following would not be a duplicate:**

Record 1: Name1, Large, 0001

Record 1: Name1, Medium, 0002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` with `MAX(ref)` to return one row for each name/type combination. Select the largest ref for each row.

`HAVING` is added to return a row only if that name/type combination has several rows.

```
select Name, Type, max(Ref)
from tablename
group by Name, Type
having count(*) > 1
```